# How does Visual Studio integrate with Unreal Engine better than Code::Blocks does?

Tags: unreal, visual-studio, ide

Background: I want to start using Unreal Engine 4, but I'm not sure which IDE I should use. I've narrowed it down to Code::Blocks (which I want for a couple good reasons) and Visual Studio 2015 (which is the industry standard).

I know that Unreal is made to use VS and it thus integrates far better with it (e.g. debugging Unreal projects apparently works in VS but not C::B). However, I haven't found any other examples of VS's superiority in this situation, and without the context of Unreal I would definitely like to use Code::Blocks instead<sup>1</sup>.

So, how does VS integrate with Unreal better than C::B does?

Note: I am not asking which is better, and I am not asking for a general comparison between the two. I just want to know exactly why people say VS is better with Unreal, so I can make an informed decision.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Reasons: I am likely going to want to be on Linux in the near future, so I would like to get used to Code::Blocks now instead of having to learn how to use two different IDEs. Also, I am working on coding with some of my friends and for various reasons they won't/can't use VS. I would prefer to use the same IDE as them, so that we can keep stuff consistent.</sup>

Comment: I'm a VS fanboy, so I'm biased, but VS has an integrated profiler :P But I never worked with Unreal, so this is not an answer to your question :)